# Rails 3 - How can I get rid of "test.host"?

Tags: ruby-on-rails-3, automated-tests, ruby-on-rails-plugins

I recently installed a plugin called [Gretel](https://github.com/lassebunk/gretel) to take care of breadcrumbs for me. It seems to be working great, except that it appears to be breaking some of my specs with the following error:

```
 Failure/Error: response.should redirect_to @course
 Expected response to be a redirect to </courses/904> but was a redirect to
 <http://test.host/courses/904>
```

**What can I do to get rid of this error?** The path seems totally correct, with the exception of that pesky test.host thing.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You are probably testing against my_model_url instead of my_model_path

The former does a full URI - including the host. The latter is a relative path without the host.

Go have a check in your controller and see if it uses _path or _url - and use the same one in your test-cases.

Comment: Thanks! As a note to others, it wasn't explicitly obvious that I was checking against a URL in my test. In my controller I had "redirect_to @course" and in my tests I also had "response.should redirect_to @course". Apparently something is different between the two (which I don't quite understand yet), and I needed to more explicitly define the path in the tests as "response.should redirect_to course_path(@course)" in my tests to make it work.

Comment: Cool - good to know. I guess the redirect_to(@course) just defaults to the full path.

Answer (score 1):

You need to expliclty  define your request body..Here i have Application that uses rails 3.0...i am using Devise for authentication..and i get a customised domain that user specifies.

```
#get user from fixtures OR create them

  @user = users(:user1)

  #used devise "sign_in for testing"

    sign_in :user, @user  
  #defined my request

   request.host = 'myblog.free-blog.com'

  #get 'show_blog"

  get 'show'
```